# Excel VBA to SUMIF Range only if Range is not completely Blank

Tags: vba, excel, sum, sumifs

I have a data issue that has been perplexing me for a few weeks now.

Goal:
- Sum set range into new reference cell. Perform this for 8 different ranges spanning 42 columns. This needs to be performed on a row by row basis so each entry has their appropriate numbers.
- Columns L:S should only have a value if the SUM range itself had any values. No false 0's.

Issues:
- The SUM Function works, but it is returning a 0 in situations when there were no values to Sum. This is an issue as 0 is a valid value, and the extra 0's throw off averages of those who actually have values.
- SUMIFS is returning TRUE instead of a value (I use SUMIFS with 1 criteria as it is easier for me to understand, don't focus on that bit as it did the same thing when I had it in the SUMIF formula).

Here is my VBA in it's entirety:

```
Sub BE_Candidate_Flow_Time()
'
' BE_Candidate_Flow_Time Macro
'
Dim StartCell As Range
Dim RangeName As String
Dim myValue As Variant

Set StartCell = Range("A1")

myValue = InputBox("Enter Date: YY-MMM")

StartCell.CurrentRegion.Select
RangeName = "Dataset"

Dim LRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long

LRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Columns("J:Q").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Columns("A:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "Application ID"
Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "Timeframe"
Range("K1").FormulaR1C1 = "Job Code"
Range("L1").FormulaR1C1 = "Time to Complete the Assessment"
Range("M1").FormulaR1C1 = "Applied/Assessed and Ready for Review"
Range("N1").FormulaR1C1 = "Time being Reviewed and Interviewed"
Range("O1").FormulaR1C1 = "Time to Accept the Offer"
Range("P1").FormulaR1C1 = "Consent to Pre-Hire Screenings"
Range("Q1").FormulaR1C1 = "Run the Pre-Hire Screenings"
Range("R1").FormulaR1C1 = "Waiting to be sent to Onboard"
Range("S1").FormulaR1C1 = "In Onboard"

Range("A2", "A" & LRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[2],RC[5])"
Range("B2", "B" & LRow).Value = myValue
Columns("T:BI").NumberFormat = "0.00"
Range("L2", "L" & LRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS({RC[9];RC[13]},{RC[9];RC[13]}," <> ")"
Range("M2", "M" & LRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS({RC[7];RC[9]:RC[11];RC[13]:RC[16]},{RC[7];RC[9]:RC[11];RC[13]:RC[16]}," <> ")"
Range("N2", "N" & LRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS({RC[16]:RC[27]},{RC[16]:RC[27]}," <> ")"
Range("O2", "O" & LRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS({RC[27]:RC[31];RC[33]:RC[34]},{RC[27]:RC[31];RC[33]:RC[34]}," <> ")"
Range("P2", "P" & LRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS({RC[34]},{RC[34]}," <> ")"
Range("Q2", "Q" & LRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS({RC[35]:RC[40]},{RC[35]:RC[40]}," <> ")"
Range("R2", "R" & LRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS({RC[40]:RC[41]},{RC[40]:RC[41]}," <> ")"
Range("S2", "S" & LRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS({RC[41]:RC[42]},{RC[41]:RC[42]}," <> ")"

Range("K1", "K" & LRow).AutoFilter 1, ""
Range("K2", "K" & LRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"
[K1].AutoFilter

Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Range("J:J,T:BI").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

Range("A1").Select
```

End Sub

Comment: What's with the "Not equal to"s (`<>`):  Writing `Range("L2", "L" & LRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS({RC[9];RC[13]},{RC[9];RC[13]}," <> ")"` will be the same a writing `Range("L2", "L" & LRow).FormulaR1C1 = TRUE`

Comment: I think that is the problem. The formula I have is returning TRUE when I need a SUM of the range if the entire range is not blank, per line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a if to the formula directly.
Somthing like

```
=IF(
     count({RC[7];RC[9]:RC[11];RC[13]:RC[16]})>0;
     SUM({RC[7];RC[9]:RC[11];RC[13]:RC[16]};
     ""
 )
```

Comment: I'd go with `IF(COUNT(Range)>0,SUM(Range),"")`, to differentate between "all cells blank" and "all cells `0`"

Comment: I see where you are going with this, but apologies as I have not had luck with IF analysis. I replaced the first SUMIFS line with the below, but I am getting the 1004 error "Application-defined or object-defined error"
   -------   
Range("L2", "L" & LRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(count({RC[9];RC[13]})>0;SUM({RC[9];RC[13]});"")"